# Reconstructing dmidecode binary dump from /sys/firmware/dmi/tables

Tags: sysfs, dmidecode

## Background

dmidecode utility is able to create a raw binary dump using `--dump-bin` option:

```
root@here:~$ dmidecode --dump-bin foo.dump
```

which can be re-used on another machine, producing effect as if dmidecode is running on the original machine:

```
me@elsewhere:~$ dmidecode --dump-bin foo.dump
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
68 structures occupying 2688 bytes.
Table at 0xBAE9D000.
[...]
```

I do have these binaries from some machines and use them for testing a script that wraps around dmidecode (hence, I need to simulate dmidecode behavior as if the hardware setup was different).

## Problem

But from a several machines, I don't have the raw binary, but *do* have copy of /sys/firmware/dmi/tables as exposed by 4.* kernel.  [Docs at kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-firmware-dmi-tables) say:

> [...]
>   The dmi/tables provides raw SMBIOS entry point and DMI tables
>   through sysfs as an alternative to utilities reading them
>   from /dev/mem. The raw SMBIOS entry point and DMI table are
>   presented as binary attributes and are accessible via:
>
> ```
> /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point
> /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI
> ```
>
> The complete DMI information can be obtained using these two
>   tables.

## Question

Is it possible to use the /sys/firmware/dmi/tables files to re-construct (in a Bash/Python/Perl/... script) the raw binary dump so that it can be re-used as in first example?

I tried to just cat the files together but I was not successful (`Invalid entry length (0). DMI table is broken! Stop.`).

Comment: In my Lamobo R1 I am fortunate enough to also have the tables. However I am considering buying hardware in a near future, and I am aware of this problem. Just to be sure, are you talking about ARM SBCs with closed design where the vendor hacked some kernel by hand?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm "harvesting" the data from [a Beaker testing repo](https://github.com/beaker-project/lshw-tests.git). The set is relatively diverse; there are various types of machines (even a laptop). I'd guess they were collected using some recent RHEL or Fedora version.  ... did that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can ref code from https://github.com/mirror/dmidecode/blob/master/dmidecode.c . Good luck for you.

[image]

Example:
7f + 00 + 80 + 30 + 7b = 18a

18a hold 8bit = 8a

New address of DMI is hard coded to 0x20.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a hex dump of `smbios_entry_point` with the binary output of dmidecode, you'll see it is *similar* to bytes 0-31 of dmidecode's output. Likewise, `DMI` matches bytes 32+. Byte 32 is missing; I assume it's always null.

It looks close enough that I had hopes of it working.

```
echo -en '\0' >NUL
sudo cat /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point NUL /sys/firmware/dmi/tables/DMI >table
dmidecode --from-dump table
```

However, dmidecode crashes with the following output:

```
# dmidecode 2.12-dmifs
Reading SMBIOS/DMI data from file table.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.
Bus error (core dumped)
```

The SMBIOS/DMI spec is [available on the internet (pdf)](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.8.0.pdf); it shouldn't be too hard to determine acceptable dummy values for the header. I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader, at least for the moment ;)